# How to pass properties to MySQL StatementInterceptor in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, aws-xray

I'm making a custom MySQL `StatementInterceptorV2`, and would like to pass some custom properties to it (such as some arbitrary `String`s).  Considering the fact that statement interceptors are created like this (according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html):

```
public Connection getDatabaseConnection(String jdbcUrl, String dbUser, String dbPassword) throws SQLException
{
    Properties dbProps = new Properties();

    dbProps.put("statementInterceptors", "package.path.to.ConnectionInterceptor");
    dbProps.put("user", dbUser);
    dbProps.put("password", dbPassword);

    return DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, dbProps);
}
```

How do I pass values to it?  I'm obviously not invoking a constructor or anything, which would be the normal way to do something like this.  Here's my statement interceptor, if it helps at all.

```
public class ConnectionInterceptor implements StatementInterceptorV2
{
    @Override
    public void init(Connection conn, Properties props) throws SQLException {

    }

    @Override
    public ResultSetInternalMethods preProcess(String sql,
                                               Statement interceptedStatement,
                                               Connection connection) throws SQLException {

        Subsegment subsegment = AWSXRay.beginSubsegment(connection.getHost());

        subsegment.putSql("url", connection.getHost());
        String user = connection.getProperties().getProperty("user");
        if(user != null) {
            subsegment.putSql("user", user);
        }
        subsegment.putSql("database_type", connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
        subsegment.putSql("database_version", connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion());
        subsegment.putSql("driver_version", connection.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());

        String finalSql = sql;
        // SQL is null in a prepared statement, so we have to grab the SQL from the statement itself
        if(interceptedStatement instanceof PreparedStatement) {
            finalSql = ((PreparedStatement) interceptedStatement).getPreparedSql();
        }
        subsegment.putSql("sanitized_query", finalSql);
        subsegment.setNamespace(Namespace.REMOTE.toString());

        // Return null to return ResultSet as is, without modification
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean executeTopLevelOnly() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public ResultSetInternalMethods postProcess(String sql,
                                                Statement interceptedStatement,
                                                ResultSetInternalMethods originalResultSet,
                                                Connection connection,
                                                int warningCount,
                                                boolean noIndexUsed,
                                                boolean noGoodIndexUsed,
                                                SQLException statementException) throws SQLException {
        AWSXRay.endSubsegment();

        // Return null to return ResultSet as is, without modification
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is passing custom properties in via the `Properties` object the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class called ConnectionInterceptorParameters which has a static threadlocal parameters. You can populate the thread local in your business logic before making the sql call and the interceptor can use those values. Then you must clear the threadlocal after you are done with the call.